# Структуры и функции

Tags: c, функции, структуры, параметры

Хочу передать в функцию переменную составного типа(структурную).
Возможно ли передать в функцию по ссылке (то есть чтобы функцию изменяла оригинальную переменную ) или возможно только копировать(передать по значению) , не изменяя значение оригинала ?

Еще один вопрос:структура должна объявляться глобально(до `main`) или внутри `main`?

И ещё один вопрос: почему при объявлении внутри `main` уже нельзя писать имя структурной переменной. Я имею в виду это:

```
struct complex_type  // имя структуры
{
  double real;
  double imag;
} number; // вот про эту строчку говорю
```

Вот не знаю, как тут поступить, вот для передачи параметров в функцию нужно объявлять структуру вне `main`?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void func( struct ION book.pages )
{

}


int main()
{

    struct day
    {
        char weekend[30];
    };

    struct ION
    {

        int pages;
        char title[67];
        struct day bd;
    };

    struct ION book;

    book.pages = 190;
    func(book.pages);
    printf("%d",book.pages);
    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз это С (не С++!), то передачи по ссылке никакой нет. Можно передать по значению... адрес :)

```
void func(struct ION * book)
{
    ...
}
```

Только вот именовать аргумент `book.pages` - это уже что-то запредельное :)

Естественно, что до объявления функции компилятор должен знать, что означает передаваемый параметр - так что такая структура должна быть объявлена глобально.

Т.е. ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct day
{
    char weekend[30];
};

struct ION
{
    int pages;
    char title[67];
    struct day bd;
};


void func(struct ION * book)
{
    book->pages++;
}


int main()
{
    struct ION book;
    book.pages = 190;
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    func(&book);
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

**Update**

Если вы хотите использовать в функции только одно поле, то нет смысла передавать всю структуру:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct day
{
    char weekend[30];
};

struct ION
{
    int pages;
    char title[67];
    struct day bd;
};


void func(int * pages)
{
    (*pages)++;
}


int main()
{
    struct ION book;
    book.pages = 190;
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    func(&book.pages);
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: я имел в виду , вызывать из главной программы  func_name(&book.pages)      , а в самой функции func_name(struct ION *book.pages){}

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: а просто копировать в функцию можно?

Comment: Можно. Но при этом все, что будет сделано в функции, будет сделано **с копией** и не повлияет на оригинал.

Comment: а можно ли это записать по-другому     book->pages++;

Comment: Простите, я уже просто перестал вас понимать, что вы хотите...

Comment: ,нет-нет,всё круто, я понял , спасибо ;)

Comment: ,просто хочу увидеть все возможные варианты записи, чтобы понимать происходящее

Answer (score 2):

> Возможно ли передать в функцию по ссылке

В си нет ссылок, можно передать указатель. https://ideone.com/NbeSNf

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct complex_type
{
  double real;
  double imag;
};

double f(struct complex_type *number)
{
  number->imag = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct complex_type x = { 7, 42 };
  printf("%f %f\n", x.real, x.imag);

  f(&x);
  printf("%f %f\n", x.real, x.imag);

  return 0;
}
```

> структура должна объявляться глобально(до main) или внутри main?

Глобально.

> Почему при объявлении внутри main уже нельзя писать имя структурной переменной.

Можно: https://ideone.com/646zqO

Answer (score 0):

Kонкретные аргументы передаются при вызове функции, а  не при определении.  Функция должна иметь аргументы того типа, с каким вы собираетесь работать. Ваш  `book.pages` имеет тип `int`, если вы хотите передать  его , то функция должна определяться с указателем на этот тип

```
void func(int* p)  
{
   ++(*p);
}
```

а потом вызывайте с вашим конкретным аргументом

```
int main()
{
    struct ION book;
    book.pages = 190;
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    func( &book.pages); 
    printf("%d\n",book.pages);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

вы хотели это как мне показалось